# how to create private route in react router dom version 6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
//prtvate route in react router dom version 6    

function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  let auth = useAuth();
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() => auth
        ? children
        : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }
    />
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/" component={Public} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/private" component={Private} />
      //private route
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

In React Router Dom v6, you must use `<Navigate to="/login" />` not `<Redirect to="/login" />`